# Issue in Einstein analytics Dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics

Here , I'm trying to add a filter to a step named "Tech_Testing_1" using "Date binding" step named (Snapshot_Binding_1) but facing a syntax error ..

Please find the saql queries being used in the attachment with the error screenshot.

Any idea??

JSON COde:

Date Binding Step Query:-

Snapshot_Binding_1:-

```
q = load \"PMO_V3\";
q = group q by ('Snapshot_Date_Year', 'Snapshot_Date_Month', 'Snapshot_Date_Day');
q = foreach q generate 'Snapshot_Date_Year' + \"~~~\" + 'Snapshot_Date_Month' + \"~~~\" + 'Snapshot_Date_Day' as 'Snapshot_Date_Year~~~Snapshot_Date_Month~~~Snapshot_Date_Day';
q = order q by 'Snapshot_Date_Year~~~Snapshot_Date_Month~~~Snapshot_Date_Day' desc;\
q = limit q 1;
```

Using the Binding logic in the below query:-

Tech_Testing_1:-

```
"query": "q = load \"PMO_V3\";\r\nq = filter q by date('Snapshot_Date_Year', 'Snapshot_Date_Month', 'Snapshot_Date_Day') in [{{column(Snapshot_Binding_1.result, [\"Snapshot_Date_Year~~~Snapshot_Date_Month~~~Snapshot_Date_Day\"]).asObject()}}];\nq = group q by ('ProjectID.Name' , 'Accountjoin.Name');\r\nresult = foreach q generate sum(q.'ProjectID.TransfProject.Technology_Readiness_Status_Numerator__c') as 'A', sum(q.'ProjectID.TransfProject.Technology_Readiness_Status_Denominator__c') as 'B',row_number() over([..] partition by 'ProjectID.Name' order by 'Accountjoin.Name' desc) as 'Row Number','ProjectID.Name' as 'ProjectID.Name','Accountjoin.Name' as 'Accountjoin.Name';\r\nresult = filter result by 'Row Number' in [1];\r\nresult = foreach result generate 'A','B';\r\nresult1 = group result by 'all';\r\nresult1 = foreach result1 generate sum('A') as 'A',sum('B') as 'B';\r\nresult1 = foreach result1 generate round(((A/B)*100),2) as 'C';\r\nresult1 = limit result1 2000;",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add 'Snapshot_Date_Year','Snapshot_Date_Month','Snapshot_Date_Day' columns to Snapshot_Binding_1 and then try to use Data Range filter in Snapshot_Binding_1 step.

Snapshot_Binding_1:-

```
q = load \"PMO_V3\";
q = group q by ('Snapshot_Date_Year', 'Snapshot_Date_Month', 'Snapshot_Date_Day');
q = foreach q generate 'Snapshot_Date_Year' + \"~~~\" + 'Snapshot_Date_Month' + \"~~~\" + 'Snapshot_Date_Day' as 'Snapshot_Date_Year~~~Snapshot_Date_Month~~~Snapshot_Date_Day','Snapshot_Date_Year','Snapshot_Date_Month','Snapshot_Date_Day';
q = order q by 'Snapshot_Date_Year~~~Snapshot_Date_Month~~~Snapshot_Date_Day' desc;
q = limit q 1;
```

Tech_Testing_1:-

```
q = load "PMO_V3";
q = filter q by date('Snapshot_Date_Year', 'Snapshot_Date_Month', 'Snapshot_Date_Day') in [dateRange([{{cell(Snapshot_Binding_1.result,0,"Snapshot_Date_Year").asString()}},{{cell(Snapshot_Binding_1.result,0,"Snapshot_Date_Month").asString()}},{{cell(Snapshot_Binding_1.result,0,"Snapshot_Date_Day").asString()}}],[{{cell(Snapshot_Binding_1.result,0,"Snapshot_Date_Year").asString()}},{{cell(Snapshot_Binding_1.result,0,"Snapshot_Date_Month").asString()}},{{cell(Snapshot_Binding_1.result,0,"Snapshot_Date_Day").asString()}}])];
q = group q by ('ProjectID.Name' , 'Accountjoin.Name');
result = foreach q generate sum(q.'ProjectID.TransfProject.Technology_Readiness_Status_Numerator__c') as 'A', sum(q.'ProjectID.TransfProject.Technology_Readiness_Status_Denominator__c') as 'B',row_number() over([..] partition by 'ProjectID.Name' order by 'Accountjoin.Name' desc) as 'Row Number','ProjectID.Name' as 'ProjectID.Name','Accountjoin.Name' as 'Accountjoin.Name';
result = filter result by 'Row Number' in [1];
result = foreach result generate 'A','B';
result1 = group result by 'all';
result1 = foreach result1 generate sum('A') as 'A',sum('B') as 'B';
result1 = foreach result1 generate round(((A/B)*100),2) as 'C';
result1 = limit result1 2000;
```